# when some microservice goes down then there is a chance to change IP address when it reloaded..then, how to set IP and port of each microservices?

Tags: flask, microservices, dcos

I'm going to deploy my microservices on DCOS, and they will communicate using REST API with each other

I know when some microservice(ex: regist user , create post ...so on) goes down, then it will be reloaded

and it could have different ip address. so i'm very confused

how to set ip and port about each microservices??

this picture is about ip changing situation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQ69.png)

as you see in this picture, ip address changed between 192.168.0.122~192.168.0.125

Comment: I am not sure of DCOS but using IPs in microservices is definitely not a good idea. Services will restart and go down , Either use DNS or better service mesh to avoid this problem .

Comment: @ImranArshad could you give me a short example about linking each services? no need to be DCOS example.

Comment: You need to use http to access the services. e.g. There is another orchestration service called Kubernetes. You expose the services by service name. Each service represent underlining containers and every other container inside the cluster can access the service by service name (http://myservicesname:port) over http. So Services are accessible within the cluster and each service is essentially pointing to containers. There should be a way in DCOS where you can access the containers over http using service abstraction layer.

Comment: I see. I guess DCOS is not an interesting platform for many MSA developers. there are fewer examples than Kubernetes on the Internet. anyway thanks a lot, @ImranArshad you give me a good hint